# How can I get the monthly maximum (and only the maximum) temperature in CDO

Tags: datagrid, max, temperature, cdo-climate

[image]I have a file with daily temperature data from 1972 to 2022, with a gridsize of 841 for each timestep. When I use -monmax command, I get three columns on the screen: min|mean|max, but I only want the max column, how can I get that information in a file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply the code you used when asking questions. I do not see how it is possible for `monmax` to give you min,mean, max. It will only give you the monthly maximum and the new variable names will be the same as in the original netCDF file. So I do not understand how you are getting min|mean|max. This sounds like impossible behaviour for CDO

Comment: I´ve uploaded an image to let you see what I mean. In that example I used -monmax command to see the maximum temperature of two months only.

Comment: You are misunderstanding something. monmax will give you the monthly max in each grid cell. The min/mean/max in `cdo sinfo` will just tell you the min/mean/max across *all* grid cells.